# JMS serializer. How to use Exclude condition?

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

i'm using JMS serializer in my symfony project and i have a question about "Exlude condition". Is it possible to specify that one property of entity would be exlude for all routes (methods) exept one.
 I mean something like this:

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="full_name", type="text", nullable=true)
 * @JMS\Exlude(if="!someAction()")
 */
private $fullName;
```

If this possible, what is the correct syntax for this? Thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To utilize `@Exclude` annotation, you need to have a bit of Symfony's [ExpressionLanguage](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html) understanding.

Obviously, the function used in the annotation (e.g. `someAction()`) does not belong to the current object but rather to Expression language instance. To register it, do the following:

```
$language = new ExpressionLanguage();
$language->register('someAction', function(){}, function ($arguments, $object) {

    // your logic goes here

    return false;
});
```

Then bind it to your serializer:

```
$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()
    ->setExpressionEvaluator(new ExpressionEvaluator($language))
    ->build();
```

Then you should be able to serialize using this exclusion strategy:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="full_name", type="text", nullable=true)
 * @JMS\Exlude(if="!someAction(object)")
 */
private $fullName;
```

The one thing I am unsure of is passing empty callable to `register` call (for compiler) and I have no means of giving it a spin and confirming that is valid.

Hope this helps...